# Conditionally grab data via useContext in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Taking into consideration https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html, we are curious if there is a valid solution to what we are trying to do. We have the dummy component:

```
function FancyComponent({ names = [], id = null, type = 'typeA' }) {
    ...
    const { ourInfosObj } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    ...
}
```

This component only needs `ourInfosObj` when `type = 'typeA'`, otherwise `ourInfosObj` is not used throughout the rest of the component. We know that we cannot wrap `const { ourInfosObj } = useContext(GlobalContext);` in an if statement. However, perhaps there is another approach? We tried:

```
function FancyComponent({ names = [], id = null, type = 'typeA' }) {
    ...
    const { ourInfosObj } = useContext(type === 'typeA' ? GlobalContext : null);
    ...
}
```

but this is clearly not good, throws an error `Cannot read properties of null (reading '_context')`.

Answer (score 0):

well since you are destructing a property that should be the result of `useContext(GlobalContext)`

if `type === typeA`
or should be set to a `null` value otherwise

in my opinion the correct approach should be something like this

```
const { ourInfosObj } =type === 'typeA' ? useContext(GlobalContext) : {ourInfosObj:null};
```

Comment: Wouldn't this count as conditionally calling a hook, which breaks the main rule of hooks?

Comment: i think you are correct 
maybe someone will be able to tell us another solution very soon

Comment: This code does seem to be working on our end. I think (and i could very well be wrong here) as long as the component's `type` prop doesn't change dynamically, thus rendering a hook that was previously not rendered (or vice versa), that this code is otherwise okay.